# UIAnimation loop endlessly until I press a button... How?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have this following animation that I want to loop around, until I press a button, then I want it to stop animating. Thing is, when I press the button repeatedly, the animation just goes weird and out of its speed... Any help to fix this and make it more fluid and normal? Thank you!
Here's my code:

```
func animate(){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: {self.blueBar.center = CGPointMake(self.blueBar.center.x + 550, self.blueBar.center.y + 550)
        }, completion: {(value: Bool) in
            if !self.buttonHasBeenPressed {
                self.animate()
            }
    })
}
```

EDIT: Code for the action that triggers and stops the animation:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if !timerIsGoing {

        buttonHasBeenPressed = false

        animate()

        futureTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() + 5.0000000

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
            0.02,
            target: self,
            selector: ("update"),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)


    } else {

        if labelValue != 0.00000 {

        } else {

        }
        timer.invalidate()
        if labelValue == -0 {
            labelValue = 0
        }
        labelTime.text = String(format: "%0.5f", labelValue)

        buttonHasBeenPressed = true


        timerIsGoing = false

    }
```

Comment: "when I press the button repeatedly, the animation just goes weird and out of its speed..." Well that's clear as mud. What is that supposed to mean? If the problem is with clicking a button, you need to provide details on what happens when you click the button. Is it tied to an IBAction? So post the code for that IBAction. Does it link to a segue? Tell us that. If the button code only sets a flag `buttonHasBeenPressed` then your code should simply stop the animation when the current iteration finishes, so there is more going on that your readers can't know about unless you tell us.

Comment: Ok im sorry ill edit the post! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to remove animations related to your view when you press the button ?

```
yourView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

You will need to reset self.blueBar.center point to its original value if you relaunch the animation.

But you should better use Core Animation to have more control on your animation

Comment: I cant seem to be able to do that removeAllAnimations method, its not there for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a jumbled mess.

The current problem looks to me like it's your touchesBegan method never sets timerIsGoing to true, so if you press the button again, it invokes `animate()` a second time.

Why are you using touchesBegan on a button? What class is that code located in? A custom subclass of UIButton? Your view controller?

It makes more sense to have you button code in an IBAction method that is tied to a touchUpInside event from the button.

Comment: It's a mess because I took a lot of stuff in my code to put here. I do set it to true sorry I accidentaly removed it! I use the touchesBegan to recognize a touch in the background, it's my button basically

Comment: If you want help the devil is in the details. You can't paste "the code looks sort of like this" and expect meaningful help. "it's my button basically?" What does that mean?